# what the difference between es.scroll.limit and es.scroll.size

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am totally confused about these two parameters,

```
es.scroll.size
es.scroll.limit
```

I did some test,still not figure out.

```
es.scroll.limit = es.scroll.size * num_of_scrolls ???
```

Answer (score 1):

`es.scroll.size` and `es.scroll.limit` are both configuration parameters passed to `elasticsearch.hadoop` when issuing requests from a distributed cluster, like Apache-Spark for exmaple.

Before reading about those two parameters, It is important to understand this about `elasticsearch.hadoop` from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/arch.html#arch-reading):

> Shards play a critical role when
>   reading information from Elasticsearch. Since it acts as a source,
>   **elasticsearch-hadoop will create one Hadoop InputSplit per
>   Elasticsearch shard, or in case of Apache Spark one Partition, that is
>   given a query that works against index I.** elasticsearch-hadoop will
>   dynamically discover the number of shards backing I and then for each
>   shard will create, in case of Hadoop an input split (which will
>   determine the maximum number of Hadoop tasks to be executed) or in
>   case of Spark a partition which will determine the RDD maximum
>   parallelism.

So we learn that the number of shards effect the number of queries run. It was also said [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-scroll-through-an-elasticsearch-index-using-elasticsearch-spark/144618/2) by james.baiera - a ES team member that:

> ES-Hadoop uses the scroll endpoint to collect all the data for
>   processing within Spark. ES-Hadoop performs the **multiple scroll
>   requests** under the hood on its own...

So the cluster created a scroll request for each partition that in turn was created for each shard! Each of those scrolls are being effected by the above mentiond `limit` and `size` parameters.

Again, per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html):

> **es.scroll.size (default 50)**
>
> Number of results/items returned by each
>   individual per request.
>
> **es.scroll.limit (default -1)**
>
> Number of total results/items returned by
>   each individual scroll. A negative value indicates that all documents
>   that match should be returned. Do note that this applies per scroll
>   which is typically bound to one of the job tasks. Thus the total
>   number of documents returned is LIMIT * NUMBER_OF_SCROLLS (OR TASKS)

`Size` states the number of documents requested by each **call** of the scroll and not the whole scroll.

`Limit` specifies the maximum number of documents to retrieve in all calls for **that** scroll API call (remember there are as many scroll API calls as there are shard in the index?)

So now this calculation makes sense:

*Total number of documents retrieved by the whole cluster = limit of each scroll API call (`es.scroll.limit`) * number of scroll calls (one per shard in the index).*

When trying this out myself I got sane results, I queried an index with 14 shards, `limit` was `1` and indeed the cluster pulled 14 docs.

As nefo_x stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200248/10047211), indeed the `limit` will also limit the `size` and that's only resonable - each call inside the entire scroll API call shouldn't be larger then the entire limit of all calls by that scroll API call, right?